# Always show "0" value in Stacked Column Chart

Tags: highcharts

I need to set chart configuration to always show all chart data values.

Check out this [chart demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HsPfB/).

"0" value on first stacked column is not visible.

I know for solution:

```
config.yAxis.min = -1;
```

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `minPointLength`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/HsPfB/2/